# Mysql - Search a text in different columns by whitespace separated

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have 3 tables (drug, generic, product). Drug & generic are master tables.
 and products belongs to drug & generic. 
Refer Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b437e/1 
Now i want to search a text in these 3 tables like below.

### Example :

Products Table Rows: 
 1 => Multum Abarelix
 2 => Haemophilus
3 => Halcion

Drugs Table Rows:
1 => hydroxyphenyl

Generics Table Rows:
1 => Acetaminophen

If I search a text **'Multum Halcion hydroxyphenyl Acetaminophen'**, then I have to get the rows that have these related texts.

### Need Result Should be like:

Products Table Rows: 
 1 => Multum Abarelix
3 => Halcion

Drugs Table Rows:
1 => hydroxyphenyl

Generics Table Rows:
1 => Acetaminophen

Query

```
select a.product_id, a.product_name, b.generic_name, c.drug_name 
from product a
join generic b
on b.generic_id = a.generic_id
join drug c
on c.drug_id = a.drug_id
where a.product_name like '%Multum Halcion hydroxyphenyl Acetaminophen%'
or b.generic_name like '%Multum Halcion hydroxyphenyl Acetaminophen%'
or c.drug_name like '%Multum Halcion hydroxyphenyl Acetaminophen%'
```

Kindly give me some queries to get this result.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the create statement of table and the query through which you are fetching the result.
You need to index the name columns of respective column to FULLTEXT and then you can apply the full text search.

I have made some changes in sqlfiddle. Please follow this link.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b78faa/4/0